# httpurl response code is blank in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to get mysql data from remote server www.kudossoft.in/get_data030518.php. but i am getting nothing when i check httpurl response code that is blank.
i have also add uses permission for internet in mainifest
my code is following please see.
i have also checked my php files permission that is ok.
and i am also inserting some data from another activity in same database that is working properly.

***MainActivity code:***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        getJSON("http://kudossoft.in/get_data300518.php");
    }

    private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }

    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] heroes = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");``
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you check the `httpurl response code`?

Comment: did you check what status code you are receiving? 

Try 

`if(con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            // Do normal input or output stream reading
        }`

Comment: response is blank. no error or no code showing in response recd from httpurl. System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. s can be null. Check for null before use.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }`. You forgot the e.printStackTrace(); Instead of returning null you could `return "Exception: "+ e.getMessage();` so the user of your app is informed if there is one. Check if s starts with "Exception:" in onPostExecute().

Comment: `System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());` Well what is logged?